# React UserContext Object Gives Undefined Value? (Unable to map)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**EDIT**: I console.log’d the productsArray, and found that it’s registering as undefined. I’m not sure why that is. In the comments I have the Schema as well as UserContext files :/

**EDIT 2:** It's fixed now, so I'm keeping this up just in case it helps anyway. My first mistake was not properly checking if it was sent from the backend (it wasnt). After sending it, the UserContext file (which I used to set the global state) was stringify'ing it, and I kept getting `[object Object]`, so I had to call `JSON.parse()` on it to get it working.

---

Hello,

Currently, I have an array of objects in MongoDB, which looks like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOhR1.jpg

I want to display the user information using this array, where the image source on the webpage corresponds to the `pictureUrl` part, the image title corresponds to `pictureTitle`, and the image description is `pictureDescription`. What I don't know, however, is how to implement this. I have no idea how to specifically target a value when it comes to enumerating over an array of objects.

I got the object in with UserContext and everything, but I just can't figure out the mapping (new :/)

I have the following code, which doesn't work:

```
        <motion.div className="gallery"
            variants={initialContainer}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="show">

            {
            productsArray.map(
                (item, index) => {
                return (
                    <div className="pics" key={index} onClick={() => getImg(item.pictureUrl)}>
                        <img src={item.pictureUrl} style={{ width: '100%' }} />
                        <div class="details">
                            <h2><span>{item.pictureTitle}</span></h2>
                            <p>{item.pictureDescription}</p>
                            <div className="moreDetails">
                                <StyledLinkUser to='/product/id'>Read<span className="linkUserSpan">More</span></StyledLinkUser>
                                <div class="iconLinks">
                                    <StyledLinkUserIcon to='/'><span className="fas fa-heart" /></StyledLinkUserIcon>
                                    <StyledLinkUserIcon to='/'><span className="fas fa-eye" /></StyledLinkUserIcon>
                                    <StyledLinkUserIcon to='/'><span className="fas fa-share" /></StyledLinkUserIcon>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            }

        </motion.div>
```

I obviously get a type error: `TypeError: productsArray.map` is not a function . How on Earth do I implement this? I feel like it's simple and I'm just not grasping it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: your error means ```productsArray``` is not an array yet when you do the ```map``` on it, can you show us where you set ```productsArray``` ?

Comment: You're almost certainly not checking for the base case where you haven't gotten a response back from your server yet, so `productsArray` is whatever you set it as default (probably null or undefined). Put in an if statement that returns something while the browser waits on your server.

Comment: Please comment out the code where you've mapped the array. Then, install React dev-tools extension on your browser. Navigate to the `Components` tab in dev-tool, select the component and take a screenshot of your props and state of this component. Then edit this post and attach that screenshot of your state and props. (Specifically the details of the `UserContext` you are talking about).

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right, I haven't checked that at all! Here are my schema and UserContext files: https://imgur.com/a/AA53ZI9. How would I fix that?

Comment: @bonnopc I'm not exactly sure which to look at. There are a lot of props. Which one would you need to see?  https://imgur.com/a/mfMtBoC

Comment: change this in your initialState `productsArray: localStorage.getItem('productsArray') || []`